# How to use arithmetic expressions in the terminal?

Tags: command-line, calculator

Why I'm getting the following weird results?

```
echo &((5/3))
[5] 6733
[4]   Done                    echo

echo &(( 2 + 9 ))
[6] 6734
[5]   Done                    echo

echo &(( 3 + 99 ))
[7] 6735
[6]   Done                    echo

echo &((55 - 44))
[8] 6736
[7]   Done                    echo
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think, it should be $, not &. With & what you see is the PID of echo, not the arithmetic result.